# jQuery – How can I simplify this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm very new to jquery and only have a very basic knowledge of how it works.
This is basically what I have, and it works fine but I'm wondering if there's a way to simplify it because it seems awfully repetitive and bulky? I've tried doing this a number of different other ways, but I haven't been able to make any of them work.

```
$(".legend.a").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".box").not(".a").css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}); 
$(".legend.b").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".box").not(".b").css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}); 
$(".legend.c").on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".box").not(".c").css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}); 
$(".legend").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
```

This is the html:

```
<div id="legend">
<div class="legend a">a</div>
<div class="legend b">b</div>
<div class="legend c">c</div>
</div>
<div id="box">
<div class="box a">a</div>
<div class="box b">b</div>
<div class="box c">c</div>
</div>
```

But, not only do I have classes a, b, and c, there's another 6 or 7 other classes as well. The classes `.box .a`, `.box .b`, etc. are used more than once, or I'd just use ids, and classes `.a`, `.b`, etc. are being used to give the corresponding `.box` and `.legend` divs the same background colour.

I feel like there must be a simpler way of doing this rather than using a lot of repetition. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the class of legend for the selector

```
$('.legend').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('.box').not('.'+this.className.replace("legend","").trim()).css({'opacity':'0.4'});
});
$(".legend").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/98fww/1/)

Comment: This answers but this is dirty. What if the designer add classes to elements (using them as classes should be used, to change the rendering) ?

Comment: @dystroy thats true, this solution is limited. Using data attributes that you suggested is probably better since it's more flexible

Answer (score 2):

I would use data-attributes to keep it clean and allow proper use of the class for formatting :

```
<div id="legend">
<div class="legend" data-target="a">a</div>
<div class="legend" data-target="b">b</div>
<div class="legend" data-target="c">c</div>
</div>
<div id="box">
<div class="box a">a</div>
<div class="box b">b</div>
<div class="box c">c</div>
</div>

$('#legend').on('mouseenter','.legend', function(){
     $('.box').not('.'+$(this).data('target')).css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}).on('mouseleave','.legend', function(){
     $('.box').css({"opacity": "1.0"});
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/pakel/1/)

If a, b and c are only used to identify the boxes, then it would be even cleaner to use an id instead of a class.

[Demonstration and code using id](http://jsbin.com/pakel/2/edit)

---

For a completely different kind of solution, you may drastically simplify your JS by totally removing it (it does constrain your HTML though) :

HTML :

```
<div class="legend a">a</div>
<div class="legend b">b</div>
<div class="legend c">c</div>

<div class="box" id=a>a</div>
<div class="box" id=b>b</div>
<div class="box" id=c>c</div>
```

CSS :

```
.legend:hover ~ .box { opacity:0.4 }
.legend.a:hover ~ #a { opacity:1 }
.legend.b:hover ~ #b { opacity:1 }
.legend.c:hover ~ #c { opacity:1 }
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/pakel/3/edit)

Answer (score 2):

You can use this too.

```
$('.a, .b, .c').on('mouseenter',function(){
    $('.box').not('.'+$(this).text()).css({'opacity':'0.4'});
});
$(".legend").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
});
```

Comment: $('.a, .b, .c') will register the event handler to .box.a, .box.b, .box.c, not the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Here one solution for you

```
var chars = ['a','b','c'];
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
  var ch = chars[i];
  $(".legend."+ch).on("mouseenter", function() {
    $(".box").not("."+ch).css({"opacity": "0.4"});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of repeating it 3 times, you can do this:

```
$(".legend div").on("mouseenter", function() { //<- i assume your divs are structured like so
    $(".box").not(".a").css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}); 

$(".legend").on("mouseleave", function() {
$(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
```

or you can use .add() https://api.jquery.com/add/

```
$(".legend.a")
    .add(".legend.b")
    .add(".legend.c")
    .on("mouseenter", function() { //<- i assume your divs are structured like so
    $(".box").not(".a").css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}); 

$(".legend").on("mouseleave", function() {
$(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about putting the logic inside a function?

```
 function setOpacity (selector,notElement,opacity)
    {
      $(selector).on("mouseenter", function() {
        $(".box").not(notElement).css({"opacity": opacity});
      }); 
    }
```

cal it like

```
setOpacity(".legend.a", ".a", "0.4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div id="legend">
    <div class="legend a" data-target=".a">a</div>
    <div class="legend b" data-target=".b">b</div>
    <div class="legend c" data-target=".c">c</div>
</div>
<div id="box">
    <div class="box a">a</div>
    <div class="box b">b</div>
    <div class="box c">c</div>
</div>
```

then

```
var $boxes = $('#box .box');
$(".legend").hover(function () {
    $boxes.not($(this).data('target')).css({
        opacity: .4
    });
}, function () {
    $boxes.not($(this).data('target')).css({
        opacity: 1
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rfKG8/), Or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rfKG8/2/)

---

Or if the order of items are same in both containers then

```
var $boxes = $('#box .box');
$(".legend").hover(function (e) {
    $boxes.not(':eq(' + $(this).index() + ')').css({
        opacity: e.type == 'mouseenter' ? .4 : 1
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/2GpV3/)

Answer (score 0):

Split function for different event:

```
$(".legend").on({"mouseenter": opacityDown, "mouseleave": opacityUp});

function opacityDown() {
    $(".box").not("."+ $(this).html()).css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}
function opacityUp() {
    $(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this:

```
$(function(){
    var legend = $('.legend'),
        box = $('.box'),
        inEvent: 'mouseenter',
        outEvent: 'mouseleave',
        activeCss: {
            opacity: 0.4
        },
        inactiveCss: {
            opacity: 1
        };

    legend.on(inEvent, function(){
        var selectedClass = '.' + $(this).prop('class').replace('legend', '');

        box.not(selectedClass).css(activeCss);
    }).on(outEvent, function(){
        box.css(inactiveCss);
    });
});
```

Comment: he asked jQuery – How can I simplify this?

Comment: And by writing everything on a single line makes it simple or ... ? I did change the `if else` which I intended anyway ...

Comment: see the accepted answer or other answers ,i never said your answer is wrong .But OP asked How can i simplify this

Comment: In my opinion it's a mistake to define variables inside a function (`$(".box")`, `{ opacity: 0.4 }`, `$('.legend')`) when you can already have access from the outside so you define them only once. Therefor it's not more complicated but best practice.

Answer (score 0):

Get the name of the box you don't want to fade on mouseenter and add a class `.fade`. On mouseleave remove all `.fade` classes:

```
$(".legend").on("mouseenter", function() {
    // get the classname and remove whitespace
    var box = this.className.replace('legend', '').replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
    // add .fade to our boxes
    $('#box').find('.' + box).addClass('fade');
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    // remove .fade
    $(".box").removeClass('fade');
});
```

Your class `.fade` only has:

```
.fade {
    opacity: 0.4;
}
```

This way, you can make further CSS-adjustments without having to mess up with your javascript.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bx4ZD/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
$('#legend .legend').on('mouseenter',function(){
    var box = $(this).attr('class').split(' ').pop();
    $(".box").not("."+ box).css({"opacity": "0.4"});
}).on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(".box").css({"opacity": "1.0"});
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/98fww/2/)**